# Remove LogCat CursorWindow Error when doing a isNull on Android

Tags: android, cursor

I have a DAO approch on my Android application, database object are converted to a java Object with something like that :

```
public void populateObjectWithCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        if(!cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(Const.USER_ID)))
            this.id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Const.USER_ID));
}
```

But when isNull can not access to column, it shows errors in logcat :

> E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow
>   which has 1 rows, 2 columns.

And I would like to get ride of this, do you know if it's possible or not ? Didn't find any Exception to handle it ...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming because `getColumnIndex(String name)` method is returning -1 for column index to `getLong(int columnName)`. The method returns -1 as index when the column name provided does not exist. So check the column name by using the `getColumnName(int columnIndex)` method & use the appropriate returned column name instead of `Const.USER_ID` in `getColumnIndex(String columnName)` method. That should solve the error.

Comment: Thanks for the response, doing something like my edited previous post will solve my problem.

Comment: Did your second approach solved the error? If so remove the answer from the question.

Comment: For next people who are interested it (Thanks to @Osama) : public void populateObjectWithCursor(Cursor cursor) {
              int rowNumber = cursor.getColumnCount();
              for(int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++){
               if(cursor.getColumnName(i).equalsIgnoreCase(Const.USER_ID))
                this.id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Const.USER_ID));     
        }
        }